# Getting errors when trying to compile on Qt creator (warning treated as error)

Tags: qt, compilation, warnings, qgroundcontrol

I have been trying to compile some source codes that i got off github (qgroundcontrol) but am having constant errors and i am having difficulties fixing it..

I always get these same recurring problems;

```
error: C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated

warning: C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (932). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss
```

warning treated as error when building

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally, you have invisible Unicode characters in a line. If it happens in a single line, cut out the complete line and type it again - do not copy/paste as invariably you will get the strange character in again.
If you have a suitable editor, e.g. BBEDit, you could search / replace these characters.

Comment: i tried retyping the line but it didnt solve the problem..
as for the warning treated as error, how can i fix that?